# How to add or remove objects in nested serializers Django using update function

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, manytomanyfield

I have 2 models - Module and Room. A module can have zero or multiple rooms and a room can be added into multiple modules. So, there is a simple many-to-many relationship between them.

While updating the modules field using a put request, **I don't want to update any rooms in it, I just want to add/remove rooms in the module.** Here are my files -

module/models.py -

```
class Module(models.Model):
    module_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.TextField()
    rooms = models.ManyToManyField(Rooms)
```

rooms/models.py -

```
class Rooms(models.Model):
    room_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.TextField()
    level = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

module/serializers.py -

```
class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rooms = RoomSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        rooms_data = validated_data.pop('rooms')
        module = Module.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for data in rooms_data:
            room, created = Rooms.objects.get_or_create(**data)
            module.rooms.add(room)
        return module
```

rooms/serialier.py -

```
class RoomSerializerWrite(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    room_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = Rooms
        fields = "__all__"
```

module/views.py -

```
class add_module(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        module_serializer = ModuleSerializer(data=request.data)
        if module_serializer.is_valid():
            module_serializer.save()
            return Response(module_serializer.data['module_id'], status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(module_serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

POST request body for updating a module in POSTMAN -

```
{
    "module_id": 2,
    "rooms": [
        {
            "room_id": 2,
            "title": "4",
            "desc": "22",
            "level": "2",
        }
    ],
    "title": "4",
    "desc": "22",
}
```

**Can someone help me with the update function in module/serializer?**

Comment: How do you decide if you want to remove room or add room in the request body?

Comment: In the Put request body, i simply add or remove a room as per requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood is you don't want to update your module's rooms with your post body, actually you want to replace them. So just clear every room from m2m relationship and add new rooms from request. Something like;

```py
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    # get new rooms
    rooms_data = validated_data.get('rooms')
    
    # clear m2m relationship
    instance.rooms_set.clear()
    
    # I assume your rooms_data is a list that contains dicts with room fields
    for room_data in rooms_data:
        # get room instance
        room, created = Rooms.objects.get_or_create(**room_data)
        
        # Add it to m2m relationship
        instance.rooms.add(room)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

So if you do not send existing room to your serializer, it will be removed from m2m relationship on instance.

Comment: Thanks! It worked exactly the way I wanted.